# Excluding test folder from pom doesn't work

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have 2 sets of testing. One for junit tests and the other for db-unit testing. I want to execute only db-unit test cases in a separate phase like saying "mvn integration-test".

```
junit test cases folder: bso
db-unit test cases folder: dao
```

But when I run "mvn integration-test", it will automatically run the junit test cases too. So I excluded that junit test case folder, which is called "bso". But still it will run the test cases inside the bso folder.
See my pom file here. How can I run the test cases ONLY in "dao" folder?

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>unit-tests</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <skip>true</skip>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
           <execution>
              <id>integration-tests</id>
              <phase>integration-test</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <skip>false</skip>
                 <includes>
                   <include>**/dao/**</include>
                 </includes>
                 <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/bso/**</exclude>
                 </excludes>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Use [Maven Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)?

Comment: yes, that could be a solution. But why this is not working?

Comment: The database tests should be named like `*IT.java` where as the others should be named like `*Test.java`. You have to configure maven-failsafe-plugin and based on the convention of the naming unit tests will be executed by maven-surefire without any supplemental configuration and the integration tests `*IT.java` will be executed by maven-failsafe-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) no need for excludes/includes in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of `exclude` tag from `execution` with `id` as **integration-tests** will result in execution of tests under `dao` package.

Following is code snippet for the same:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-tests</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/dao/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you'll want to execute unit and integration tests with different plugins
Unit tests are usually handled by Maven Surefire Plugin and Integration Tests are handled by Maven Failsafe Plugin.

Why? 
Out of my head, two reasons:

- If integration tests fail you might not want to fail the build (not always the case, but still).
- The test reports are different (generated under different folders)

Surefire  by default recognizes as tests classes that end with `*Test`, Failsafe plugin works with `*IT` (integration tests) 
So place them under different folders to not mix and you're good to go.

When done check out the reports (in target folder you'll find `surefire-reports` and `failsafe-reports` folders) and see that indeed plugins pick the correct test cases